# Guarantee on size ordering on char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t

Tags: c++, c++11, character, sizeof, widechar

Does the C++ standard provide any guarantee on the ordering of the size in bytes of `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`? (any extract from the standard is welcome)

For example do I have the guarantee that:

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(wchar_t) <= sizeof(char16_t) <= sizeof(char32_t)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(wchar_t)` and `1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(char16_t) <= sizeof(char32_t)`.

5.3.3/1 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]

> ... sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1.
>   ... [ Note: in particular, sizeof(bool), sizeof(char16_t),
>   sizeof(char32_t), and sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-defined.75 —
>   end note ].

3.9.1/5 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]

> ... Type wchar_t shall have the same size, signedness, and alignment
>   requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its
>   underlying type. Types char16_t and char32_t denote distinct types
>   with the same size, signedness, and alignment as uint_least16_t and
>   uint_least32_t, respectively, in <cstdint>, called the underlying
>   types.

Update: I haven't found it in the standard. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) says for `uint_leastN_t`:

> smallest unsigned integer type with width of at least 8, 16, 32 and 64
>   bits respectively

Note that sizeof(char)==1 does *not* mean that a char has 8 bits. See also [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#bits-per-byte). [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) says about CHAR_BIT:

> number of bits in byte

1.7/1 The C ++ memory model [intro.memory]

> The fundamental storage unit in the C ++ memory model is the byte. A
>   byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic
>   execution character set (2.3) ...

Comment: I am not sure about the < size because the standard does not specify how much bits there is in a byte. If a byte is 16 bits long, then sizeof(char) == sizeof(char16_t), at least I think. It needs confirmation however...

Comment: Right. I updated my answer. I was however unable to find something which states that a C++ byte and a char have the same amount of bits.

Answer (score 0):

The types `char16_t` and `char32_t` are defined to be the same size as `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t` respectively.

No such constraints exist on `wchar_t`, except that it must be at least as large as `char` (which, of course, is true for *all* data types in C and C++).  There exist actual implementations with 1-byte, 2-byte (MSVC++), and 4-byte (GCC) wide characters.

Answer (score 0):

In 64-bit Qt Creator (using Clang), `wchar_t` is four (4) bytes.